# Using an existing EPS/PDF/AI file as a template

Tags: templates

I've been working on a product in LaTeX, and now it's time to make a box for it.

I have all of my *.sty files from the main product, so I'd like to use LaTeX here.

The box designers/printers said they would send me an EPS file, and then sent me a pair of PDF and AI (adobe illustrator) files.  These are a single page, with vectorized coloured lines which define the folds, creases and cuts.

[image]

What's the process in using this as a tex-template?

I imagine that I'm going to manually inspect the PDF to derive page geometry, then `\includegraphics{template}` it to fill that page.  Then it's a matter of creating `minipage`s for each region and manually aligning them to the template, zooming in in each preview to ensure I don't undershoot any lines.

Is that the process, or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Some meta-data about page geometry does exist (I suspect it is in `pt` units).

```
$ pdftk template.pdf dump_data
...
NumberOfPages: 1
PageMediaBegin
PageMediaNumber: 1
PageMediaRotation: 0
PageMediaRect: 0 0 1,150.87 861.732
PageMediaDimensions: 1,150.87 861.732
```

Comment: As you have the image in vector format, you could use https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz to convert it into tikz.